# Lua winapi and thread synchronization

Tags: multithreading, winapi, lua

Sorry for being lazy, but why not?

I'm trying to build lua module which would work with pipes. And I'm considering to use Donovan's winapi module for that.
The problem is that my lua module will be plugged into the other system and will get notified via callback method like OnEvent. Then it needs to call getSomeData to get detailed data, and then I want to send this data  via named pipe to my Java program (the original system doesn't support plugging Java or sending data directly)
and the problem is for me to understand how to ensure that my SomeData would be properly synchronized between winapi make_pipe_server thread and my OnEvent thread.

Do I need some special handling for that? Because from that I've read, Lua threading is not the same as OS/C/Java threading and it might not require synchronization?
SomeData is not atomic at will consist of ~10 lines of string data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Josh Simmons pointed me out that there is pretty cool ffi for lua exists:
https://github.com/jmckaskill/luaffi
(of James McKaskill)

I tried it and it works with just standard lua51.dll and custom ffi.dll used as normal lua module.

Brilliant work!

Comment: LuaJIT is drop-in replacement for Lua 5.1. LuaFFI is not as fast as LuaJIT FFI but it almost compatiable with it. So you can just replace your lua51.dll with luajit's one and try it. Also you can use socket library to communicate with external process.

Comment: wow... thanks, I was completely in sure that all the magic resides inside "luajit.exe"!
but even it is a very important comment, I think in my case such drop-in wouldn't work, since I suppose the solution there I try to plug in already uses non-standard lua.dll (it is > 700KB) to access private in memory data and functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this issues[1]
Also winapi uses global static buffer to convert strings to multibyte[2].
So if winapi uses it to open pipes this function is not thread safe.
I have problem with `watch_for_file_changes` when use this function in multithreaded environment (lua_State per os thread).
But i did not use pipes. So I think you should check source by yourself.

[1] https://github.com/stevedonovan/winapi/issues/4
[2] https://github.com/stevedonovan/winapi/blob/master/winapi.c#L38

Comment: thanks for the comment. I found out a brilliant lua ffi project, which makes available to call almost anything from lua. I will try to use it to create named pipe. I suppose as long as I create pipe, I would be able to work with it using general io api

Comment: last night I built a test with LuaJit and it works really perfect. Having Lua used Win32 API through LuaJit from one side and Java used Win32 through JNA (actually both use FFI underneath) - it is so natural and "easy"! Love that. But LuaJit is an executable, standalone. No way to plug it into other system, which runs Lua in it's own container. I don't get why don't they provide ffi to Lua as a dll...